# Making OAuth2 request in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, curl, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to make a request in angularjs to retrieve an access token, but I'm not 100% sure how to go about it. Here's the request in curl

> curl -X POST -d
>   "grant_type=password&username=&password=&scope=read"
>   -u":" http://localhost:8000/o/token/

any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to post with query string parameters

To do that you need to make some modifications in your post request

```
var request = $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "",
                    transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
                    data: {
                        grant_type: "password",
                        username: "Kim",
                        password: "123",
                        scope: "read"
                    }
                });
```

Here is explanation in more details https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
var data = "grant_type=password" + "&username="+cred.username + "&password="+cred.password +
            "&client_id=" + cred.client_id +
            "&client_secret=" + cred.client_secret;
       $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'BaseUrl',
           data: data,
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

       })
```